# How to retrieve files in Domino Web documents to embed them instead of showing them as links?

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a Notes app that was designed for the browser, not the client. It allowed upload of files into the documents, so nearly all the documents have files. The files are stored in the NSF as $FILE and displayed in the documents as links.
I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro to create PDFs from the documents and need to include the file attachments within the PDFs, however the PDFs just include links to the files, not the attachments. Can I write an agent to run against the documents to get those files and embed them within the documents? When I view those documents through the client, I see all of the HTML etc. and then at the bottom of the document, the file attachments appear. When I view these same documents in the browser, the file attachments do not appear. If I could merely ensure that they are there, then when running the PDF generator in Acrobat Pro, they would be included in the PDFs and executable.

I am really stuck here, with no other way to 'archive' this notes database with all the data intact.
Thanks in advance for any insights!!

Ginni

Answer (score 0):

There is a commercial product from [Swing Software](https://www.swingsoftware.com/blog/lotus-notes-export-to-pdf) that does this. I hear that it's quite good, but I've never used it. Let me explain why...

The way I usually end up doing this is just quick-and-dirty. I write an agent to export the files, using the document UNID as part of the filename. The same agent exports all the data fields from the document into a CSV file, and I add a column with the filename of the extracted attachment. In your case, I would add two columns -- one for the extracted attachment(s), and one for the generated PDF. The CSV serves as an index for the exported data. It can be imported into something more friendly, or just left as-is and brought up in Excel, depending on the customer's usage requirements and available systems. I've recommended Swing Software's product and offered to explore other ideas for developing code (e.g., using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) for Domino web apps to capture a WYSIWYG rendering based on an HTML crawl) for PDF rendering of Notes documents for a couple of clients, but none of them have justified the cost that would be involved in buying licenses and/or writing the code. Quick and dirty always seems to win, even when there are retention and eDiscovery considerations taken into account.